# Constant time search

Tags: algorithm, search, complexity-theory

Suppose I have a rod which I cut to pieces. Given a point on the original rod, is there a way to find out which piece it belongs to, in constant time?

For example:

```
  |------------------|---------|---------------|
  0.0                4.5       7.8532          9.123
```

Given a position:

```
                                   ^
                                   |
                                   8.005
```

I would like to get `3rd piece`.

It is possible to easily get such answer in O(log n) time with binary search but is it possible to do it in O(1)? If I pre-process the "cut" positions somehow?

Comment: That would depend on the precision required. In this simple example with 4 decimals of precision, an array of 91230 elements pre-filled with segment would give a single lookup at position 80050 to find which segment it hits.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i'm pretty sure that's not what he had in mind...

Comment: @NoIdeaForName That's why it's a good suggestion ;-) Even if it turns out impractical the same technique can be useful for other problems. It's crude and space-hungry, but very effective.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I'm interested in `float` precision. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @EcirHana How small are the smallest segments as compared to the whole rod? Any size from whole rod to minimum float precision or a minimum or maximum?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson good question! I think there could be a limit on the segment size: 0.01 - 100000.0 (maybe that's even a bit generous). What the whole length goes, I don't really know - possibly long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assume the point you want to query is uniformly randomly chosen along the rod, then you can have EXPECTED constant time solution, without crazy memory explosion, as follows.  If you break up the rod into N equally spaced pieces, where N is the number of original irregularly spaced segments you have in your rod, and then record for each of the N equal-sized pieces which of the original irregular segment(s) it overlaps, then to do a query you first just take the query point and do simple round-off to find out which equally spaced piece it lies in, then use that index to look up which of your original segments intersect the equally spaced piece, and then check each intersecting original segment to see if the segment contains your point (and you can use binary search if you want to make sure the worst-case performance is still logarithmic).  The expected running time for this approach is constant if you assume that the query point is randomly chosen along your rod, and the amount of memory is O(N) if your rod was originally cut into N irregular pieces, so no crazy memory requirements.

PROOF OF EXPECTED O(1) RUNNING TIME:

When you count the total number of intersection pairs between your original N irregular segments and the N equally-spaced pieces I propose constructing, the total number is no more than 2*(N+1) (because if you sort all the end-points of all the regular and irregular segments, a new intersection pair can always be charged to one of the end-points defining either a regular or irregular segment).  So you have a multi-set of at most 2(N+1) of your irregular segments, distributed out in some fashion among the N regular segments that they intersect.  The actual distribution of intersections among the regular segments doesn't matter.  When you have a uniform query point and compute the expected number of irregular segments that intersect the regular segment that contains the query point, each regular segment has probability 1/N of being chosen by the query point, so the expected number of intersected irregular segments that need to be checked is 2*(N+1)/N = O(1).

Comment: I can't understand this answer at all. Can you explain with an example?

Comment: I think I understand it, it's basically a "grid hash" acceleration structure. It has two problems, though: how to choose N and when several segments fall into one, equally-sized, part then it is the same problem again...

Comment: I'll update with the proof that this has expected O(1) time under the assumption that the query point is uniformly chosen along the rod.

Comment: @Ecir Note this is expected O(1) time, not worst-case O(1) time.  It's possible that all but one of the irregular segments all fall into one regular spaced segment.  But then the chance that a uniformly random query point falls into this unfortunate case is 1/N, and so even though there are N-1 irregular segments that need to be checked in this case, it still balances out to expected O(1) time because (N-1 irregular segments)*(1/N chance of occurrence with query point) = O(1) expected time.

Comment: @Ecir the "N" for the number of regular spaced segments to construct is the same "N" as the number of irregular-spaced segments that you started with.  So you're basically just doubling the amount of memory required.

Comment: Using the same number of regular segments isn't important to getting O(1) though, this was something that first confused me when reading your answer. Adjusting the length of the regular segments to the smallest irregular segment can explode the memory requirements though, so doing that is not universal. Still it's something I would consider, e.g. if the input data is not a pathological cornercase. ;)

Comment: I think this is so far the best suggestion. And thanks for the proof, very interesting...

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary cuts and precisions, not really, you have to compare the position with the various start or end points.

But, if you're only talking a small number of cuts, performance shouldn't really be an issue.

For example, even with ten segments, you only have nine comparisons, not a huge amount of computation.

Of course, you can always turn the situation into a ploynomial formula (such as `ax^4 + bx^3 +cx^2 + dx + e`), generated using simultaneous equations, which will give you a segment but the highest power tends to rise with the segment count so it's not necessarily as efficient as simple checks.

Comment: that's sounds more like a university question regarding The bounds and efficency of algorithem, not an actual program question

Comment: Isn't there a way to pre-process the positions or to build some acceleration structure to make it faster?

Comment: @EcirHana, yes, see my comment on the equations. But I'm not sure the efficiency gains will be worth it unless there are a _lot_ of segments.

Comment: Than formula trick is very interesting, thanks! But I'm not sure if I can use it as there may be many cuts, as you said. Also, you probably meant "quartic", instead of "quadratic", no?

Comment: @EcirHana: well, no, I'd never heard of quartic. I mean't quadratic-like in the sense of quadratic (highest power = 2) but an arbitrary number of powers (one per segment). Now that your comment has caused me to search, I remember the proper term is polynomial, so I'll fix that. Just out of interest, is there a likely upper limit on segment count?

Comment: @paxdiablo hmm, I don't really know. Would it help if there was a upper bound, say 2^16? (Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function)

Comment: @EcirHana, with 2^16 segments, balanced binary tree search is probably the best way, 16 comparisons at most to find a segment based on input value. That's slower than an O(1) lookup solution but (1) it's viable; and (2) you probably won't notice.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to do better than lg n with a comparison-based algorithm. Reinterpreting the 31 non-sign bits of a positive IEEE float as a 31-bit integer is an order-preserving transformation, so tries and van Emde Boas trees both are options. I would steer you first toward a three-level trie.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign an integral number to every position and then use that as index into a lookup table, which would give you constant-time lookup. This is pretty easy if your stick is short and you don't cut it into pieces that are fractions of a millimeter long. If you can get by with such an approximation, that would be my way to go.

There is one enhanced way which generalizes this even further. In each element of a lookup table, you store the middle position and the segment ID to the left and right. This makes one lookup (O(1)) plus one comparison (O(1)). The downside is that the lookup table has to be so large that you never have more than two different segments in the same table element's range. Again, it depends on your requirements and input data whether this works or not.